# Redirecting page using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

my domain is `www.yellowandred.in`

if user click on `yellowandred.in/mainWork/`, it should redirect to `yellowandred.in/mainWork.php`

and if user click on `yellowandred.in/mainWork/index` or `yellowandred.in/mainWork.php/index` it should show `404` error,please help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the first link I found in google 
http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/85/Using+.htaccess+rewrite+rules#gs

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try out this tool to help you create an htaccess file:

http://htaccessredirect.net

You will want to do a url "rewrite".

There are others also. Just search "htaccess generator".